# I am preloading images in an array and cannot call the ".src" property?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently setting up an array to preload 20 images which has been successful, but now I am wanting to call on this array to assemble the images in a table.
What is the best way to do this?
As it is giving me an error that the property of ".src" is undefined.

```
//This is the function that is currently preloading the array of images.

var imageArray = new Array();
var arrayIndex = 0;

function preloader() {
for(var r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
    for(var c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
        imageArray[arrayIndex] = new Image();
        imageArray[arrayIndex].src = "../images/bcpot00" + img + "/bcpot00" + img + "_r" + (r+1) + "_c" + (c+1) + ".jpg";
        arrayIndex++;
        console.dir(imageArray);
    }
  }
}  

//This is the function that is currently assembling the images.

function assemble() {
    for(var r = 0; r < rows; r++) {

            table += '<tr>';

                for(var c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
                    table += '<td id = "jsImg">';
                    table += '<img height = 50px width = 65px src = ' + 
                    imageArray[arrayIndex].src + '>';
                    table += '</td>';
                }

            table += '</tr>';
}
```

I expected that it would call the source from the array when 'imageArray[arrayIndex].src' was inputed but all it gave me was an undefined src property.

Comment: `imageArray[arrayIndex].src + '>';` should be `imageArray[r].src + '>';` ? (or `c`?) Or, am I missing the `arrayIndex` ?

Answer (score 3):

**imageArray** is an empty array you're populating using this for-loop:

```
for(var c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
    imageArray[arrayIndex] = new Image();
    imageArray[arrayIndex].src = "../images/bcpot00" + img + "/bcpot00" + img + "_r" + (r+1) + "_c" + (c+1) + ".jpg";
    arrayIndex++;
    console.dir(imageArray);
}
```

To refer to a specific element inside this array you're using a global variable called **arrayIndex** - which you also increment in this loop.
After this loop finishes this variable's value will keep it's last value.

Later on inside the **assemble()** function you're reusing this variable without resetting it to zero and incrementing it in the loop again.

```
        for(var c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
            table += '<td id = "jsImg">';
            table += '<img height = 50px width = 65px src = ' + 
            imageArray[arrayIndex].src + '>';
            table += '</td>';
        }
```

Try this instead:

```
function assemble() {
  arrayIndex = 0;
  for (var r = 0; r < rows; r++) {

    table += '<tr>';

    for (var c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
      table += '<td id = "jsImg">';
      table += '<img height = 50px width = 65px src = ' +
        imageArray[arrayIndex].src + '>';
      table += '</td>';
      arrayIndex++;
    }

    table += '</tr>';
  }
}
```

Comment: WOW, Thank you so SO much for that. I have been stuck on this for so long. I appreciate that very much.

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help. =)

Answer (score 0):

Just a couple of tips

You don't need to use the arrayIndex variable at all in the preloader function if you `.push` the new image into the array.

```
var imageArray = [];

function preloader() {
  for(var r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
    for(var c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
      var pic = new Image();
      pic.src = "../images/bcpot00" + img + "/bcpot00" + img + "_r" + (r+1) + "_c" + (c+1) + ".jpg";
      imageArray.push(pic);
    }
  }
}
```

Then in your assemble function you can easily compute the arrayIndex from the r and c variables

```
function assemble() {
  for(var r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
    table += '<tr>';
    for(var c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
      var arrayIndex = r * cols + c;
      table += '<td id = "jsImg">';
      table += '<img height = 50px width = 65px src = ' 
        + imageArray[arrayIndex].src + '>';
      table += '</td>';
    }
    table += '</tr>';
  }
}
```